# How To Upload Files To Server Without Domain Pointing To Nameserver

Tags: domains, dns, server, nameserver, ftp

I am planning on migrating my website from one server to another. Since this website is for my business, I don't want there to be a time frame where customers will land on an empty page.

I tried uploading the files via FTP to the server without having the domain being pointed to the server, but the server won't grant me access, even with the proper login credentials.

**Is there a way to upload files to the new nameserver without having the domain name being pointed to it?**

Comment: You are not uploading files to a name server. A name server is a DNS server. You are just uploading the files to your hosts server or shared server. In many cases, your site will be accessible via a host sub-domain. The fact that you are not able to log on tells me that you really should talk to the web host and ask them for advice. This is a common practice you are suggesting and so they should be able to help you rather quickly. They will likely give you access via a host sub-domain or IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the IP address of the new server rather than the domain name.  That will get the files there.

Alternatively you could set up a subdomain with an A record pointing to the new server IP address, have them add that subdomain in DNS at the new server and then you can FTP in.

There are a couple of ways of viewing the files once you have done that.  One common way is something like http://hostingcompany.domain/~youraccount